# How do I dynamically make threads in project based on line count in a file?

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is what I have so far:

```
from threading import Thread

import pdb

with open('data.txt') as f:
    threadcount = sum(1 for _ in f)

print "There are " + str(threadcount) + " lines/threads."
pdb.set_trace()

def Main():
    for line in threadcount:    
        line = Thread(target=timer, args=())
        line.start()

        print "Main Complete"

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
```

I am wondering how do I dynamically build up those threads in a function based on the line count; so it will iterate through creating as many threads as is needed? I'm not sure what to do/where to go next.

So I would like a thread for each line that is within the text file I am dealing with which would not be more than 10-20 lines usually.

EDIT:

Ok this is what I have now:
from threading import Thread

```
import pdb

with open('data.txt') as f:
    threadcount = sum(1 for _ in f)

print "There are " + str(threadcount) + " lines/threads."
#pdb.set_trace()

def stuff():
    print "stuff"

def Main():
    for line in xrange(threadcount):    
        #line = Thread(target=stuff, args=())
        line = Thread()
        line.start()

        print "this is thread " + str(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
```

and it produces this output:

```
There are 10 lines/threads.
this is thread <Thread(Thread-1, started 11612)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-2, started 20692)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-3, started 22232)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-4, stopped 21620)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-5, stopped 5620)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-6, started 20496)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-7, started 13844)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-8, started 17128)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-9, started 20256)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-10, started 11796)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-11, started 12416)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-12, started 7720)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-13, started 18680)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-14, started 21452)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-15, stopped 5796)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-16, started 8452)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-17, started 20388)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-18, started 16652)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-19, stopped 872)>
this is thread <Thread(Thread-20, started 16480)>
```

So why is it ending up at 20 threads rather than 10 and why is the print out showing a long load of numbers rather than just a number? something to do with changing to xrange?

Comment: What does your current code do?

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: It doesn't do anything yet. I just want it to build the threads but I am stuck on how to proceed to make the threads, what direction to take. I want somehow to make a loop which can make the threads giving each one its own unique name/number.

Comment: Put that in the question

Comment: Edited it with additions.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
for line in threadcount:
```

`threadcount` is an integer, you can only iterate over sequences.

If you want to iterate a number of times you can use [**`xrange`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange):

```
>>> for time in xrange(3):
...     print time
0
1
2
```

You need:

```
for line in xrange(threadcount):
     ...
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I wondered why I was getting errors before but I can run without errors with some edits now. So I will play around and see if I can figure it out.